# I'm new at doing signatures and my signature is a little different each time (Canada)

Tags: passports

As the title says, I never do my signature, so I've never practiced a lot. I filled out my passport application and had to sign a lot so I'm really paranoid they will send it back. It's not completely different, but it has some minor changes. Help? :(

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is likely to compare the different signatures on your form(s) to see how similarly they are written. Instead, if there is ever a question about who actually filled out your form, you could be asked "Is this your signature?" And, you can probably say whether it is or it isn't even if it's not how you might normally write it.